# Mp4Parser video not rotating

Tags: android

I am not able to rotate mp4parser video. I have an array containing path of video to be merged,all the videos in array are vertical but after merging it display horizontally. I tried alot to change the orientation but mvhd.setMatrix(Matrix.ROTATE_180); is not working at all. when i use container it gives error at "movieCreator" and when i use isofile,it works fine but orientation remain horizontal.
Please help me.

```
 public void onRunVideoClick() {
String newPath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

        Movie videoMovie;
        List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
        List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < NewVideoCaptureActivity.videoPath.size(); i++) {
                File filevideo;
                String videoFilePath;

                videoFilePath = NewVideoCaptureActivity.videoPath.get(i);



                filevideo = new File(videoFilePath);
                if (filevideo.exists() == true) {

                    videoMovie = MovieCreator.build((DataSource) new FileInputStream(videoFilePath).getChannel());

                    Track TrackVideoStart = null;
                    for (Track t4 : videoMovie.getTracks()) {
                        if (t4.getHandler().equals("vide")) {
                            TrackVideoStart = t4;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    videoTracks.add(TrackVideoStart);

                    Track TrackVideoSound = null;
                    for (Track t4 : videoMovie.getTracks()) {
                        if (t4.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                            TrackVideoSound = t4;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    audioTracks.add(TrackVideoSound);
                    AudioTime = getTrackTime(TrackVideoSound);
                }
            }

            Movie result1 = new Movie();
            result1.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
            result1.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks.toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));



            Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result1);
            MovieHeaderBox mvhd = (MovieHeaderBox) Path.getPath(out, "moov/mvhd");
            mvhd.setMatrix(Matrix.ROTATE_180);
            out.writeContainer(new FileOutputStream(newPath+ File.separator + "SampleVideos"+ File.separator + "output12.mp4").getChannel());



//          IsoFile out = (IsoFile) new DefaultMp4Builder().build (result1);
//      
//          
//          FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(String.format(newPath+ File.separator + "SampleVideos"+ File.separator + "output12.mp4"), "rw").getChannel();
//          fc.position(0);
//          out.getBox(fc);
//          fc.close();




        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```